# Show Database based on Input Value

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a table with "DUE_DATE" column, and on my page, I have an input that I want to use as the query condition.

let's say:

```
    <?php
       include 'database.php';
       $pdo = Database::connect();
       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM production WHERE DUE_DATE = "2017-10-01"';
       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';                            
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="15%">'. $row['CUSTOMER'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['ORDER_NO'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['ORDER_DATE'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['DUE_DATE'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="12%">'. $row['POC'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="12%">'. $row['TOTAL_QTY'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="13%">'. $row['ORDER_TYPE'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td style="text-align:center" width=18%>';
         echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="aafes-update.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">Update</a>';
         echo '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="aafes-delete.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">Delete</a>';
         echo '</td>';                     
        echo '</tr>';
       }
      Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Instead of writing the due date manually on my sql, I want to take the value from the input

```
    <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="due-date" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align:right">Search by Delivery Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm datepick" name="dueDate">
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control"> Go</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'm having trouble how should I write the form action, should I use $_GET or $_POST and how can I do it? Hope I am understood, thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do this dynamically on a single page. If that is the case, one option is with [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: The form action should be the page containing `<?php` and `$_POST['dueDate']` will hold the value you are sending. Also, you should use a statement if you want to put this into your query.

Comment: I have zero knowledge about AJAX yet, not necessarily that I need it to work dynamically, I just want to show a set of data based on input search

Comment: @Frederik.L exactly, but I'm really confused how would I write the code for that page

Comment: @Richelle I suggest you read on prepared statement here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php and php forms here: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: @Frederik.L thank you, I'll try to work on this